# Pgfmathsetmacro doesn't have the same printed precision if the value is negative or positive

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm expecting the values print with `\pgfmathsetmacro{\variable}{value}` have the same precision regardless the variable is positive or negative. How can I fix it and is it the expected behaviour ?

A MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\A}{-150}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\B}{150}
        \node (A) at (0,1) {Why does negative values are printed to decimal precision : $\verb+\A+=\A$ ?};
        \node (B) at (1.7,0) {and positive values are printed as : $\verb+\B+=\B$ ?};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result :

[image]

Comment: If you want to print numbers without decimals, you can use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` instead of `\pgfmathsetmacro`. But I can't tell why there is a difference in precision in the printed value.

Comment: The real answer will be some quirk in how PGFmath parses and evaluates the numbers. Assume that `150` is the exception and not the rule. As @JasperHabicht hints at, always use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` or the `int` function to get an actual integer number. (There's also `\pgfmathprintnumber` and the whole pretty-printing `siunitx`  package if you need a different kind of control for these things.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`. My question was part of looking for a solution and part of looking for a reason such a behaviour. As you solved the first part, do you mind turning it in an answer @JasperHabicht ?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I'm using it in angles (and with `siunitx` package but i'm not sure to fully understand what you mean with "fully-control for these things" with it. Are you talking about the control of the precision ? If so, then I don't want having to write `[round-mode=places,round-precision=4]` each time `\pgfmathsetmacro` doesn't act as expected.

Comment: Well, do you expect the result to be always integer? Then use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`. If you use `\A` and `\B` just as “variables” and without actually calculating anything PGFMath/`\pgfmath…macro` is the wrong tool. `\(re)newcommand` should be used instead. `\pgfmathprintnumber` and `siunitx` can be used to automatically detect things and print them nicely, might be a good idea to use here, depends on the nature of your document and how you get to these numbers. Again, if these are just variables, don't use PGFMath to define in the first place.